# Why I can't insert new data in my database using SQLITE?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

```
public class SQLiteJDBCDriverConnection {
```

This block is to connect to sqlite database and create "warehouses" table with three columns.

```
public static Connection connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        // db parameters
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:chinook.db";
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warehouses (\n"
                + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                + " name text NOT NULL,\n"
                + " capacity real\n"
                + ")";
        // create a connection to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        //Create table
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();
        state.executeUpdate(sql);

        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return conn;


}
```

This block is to create object with three parameters to insert new records for three columns.

```
public static void newItem(int id, String name, int capacity) {
    Connection con = connect();
    PreparedStatement state;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO warehouses(id,name,capacity) VALUES(?,?,?)";
try {
    state = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    state.executeUpdate();
}catch(Exception e) {

}
}
```

This block executes the newItem function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    newItem(4009,"plywood",5000);
}
}
```

Comment: Your main problem is `catch(Exception e) {}`. You swallow the error, so now you don't know what went wrong.

Comment: The other problem is that you're creating the PreparedStatement with `prepareStatement` but you're not using `setInt` and `setString` to give it the parameter values.

Comment: If you actually print or log the exception, you'll likely find it is because you set no values for the parameters in your `newItem` method. Never, ever just swallow and ignore exceptions. At minimum log them (but usually that is **not** the best course of action, at least not only logging).

Comment: I already edited it and I looked for "database connection error" seems like something is still wrong please help! this will be the only thing I need to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

You do not set parameters to your SQL query.
After `state = con.prepareStatement(sql);` you need to set actual parameters using `state.setXXX(index, value);`

```
state = con.prepareStatement(sql);
state.setInt(1, id);
state.setString(2, name);
state.setInt(3, capacity);
state.executeUpdate();
```

And as mentioned in comments you need to at least add logging to your `catch` blocks. And connection and preparedStatement objects should be closed when are not needed anymore.

**EDIT**

In your `connect` method you **close** connection object in `finally` block and return **closed** connection. And then you try to use closed connection in your `newItem()` method.

Comment: I already edited it and I looked for "database connection error" seems like something is still wrong please help! this will be the only thing I need to move forward.

Comment: Oh my. Now I got a NullPointerException. Ghis is frustrating!

Comment: If you changed your code please also update it in the question. And please also ad stacktrace for that `NullPointerException`